# Cannot share class variable across modules?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a web app that takes webhook payloads and then sends messages through a Discord bot. The web server and the bot instance are run using `asyncio`.

Here is how `configurations.py` looks like:

```
class configurations:
    config = None

    @classmethod
    def init_config(cls):
        with open ('config.yaml', 'r+') as f:
            config = yaml.safe_load(f)
            config = defaultdict(cls.default_value, config)

        return config

    @classmethod
    def default_value(cls):
        return "None"

    @classmethod
    def get_config(cls):
        if not cls.config:
            cls.config = cls.init_config()

        return cls.config

    @classmethod
    def reload_config(cls):
        with open ('config.yaml', 'r+') as f:
            latest_config = yaml.safe_load(f)
        
        cls.config = defaultdict(cls.default_value, latest_config)
```

The idea is to have `config` be a shared variable across `webhook.py` and `discordBot.py`, therefore `from configurations import configurations` is done in both files. `webhook.py` would be calling `config = configurations.get_config()` to get the config, and when the yaml file is edited, `discordBot.py` could then call `configurations.reload_config()` with a Discord command to refresh the config variable and cause `webhook.py` to operate with the latest config. However, when I run the program, the config in `webhook.py` does not actually update.

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: That's because your module-level variable `config` refers to a *particular* object that `configurations.config` *once* referred to. `reload_config` only changes which object `cls.config` refers to, without changing the object that it *previously* referred to. You'll need to do something like `cls.config.update(cls.default_value, latest_config)` instead.

Comment: @chepner Sadly, changing it to ``cls.config.update(latest_config)`` (``update()`` only takes in one parameter) still causes the same issue. What's interesting to note is that if I call ``configurations.reload_config()`` in webhook.py itself, it works. However I would really prefer the Discord bot to have a command that allows me to reload the config, therefore this solution doesn't work. Any thoughts on why this could be how it is? Thanks.

Comment: My thought is that you need to tell us how your program is put together and how these events you describe are related to each other.  Sharing a variable across modules is absolutely routine in Python and Chepner's solution must work.  As chepner explained, your first solution failed because reload_config created a NEW object, and the OLD object was already bound to the variable config in webhook.  But if you modify the internals of a dictionary, that doesn't create a new object.  You say this doesn't work, but it must: there is only one config object.  There's something you're not telling us.